# I have implemented retrofit library with gson but getting an importing error "Cannot resolve symbol 'Gson'"

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, retrofit

I have implemented retrofit library with gson but getting an importing error.

Android studio version

> Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 2 Build
> #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7678000, built on August 27, 2021

App level build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
```

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
        dataBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'

    // Import the Firebase BoM
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.3')

    // Declare the dependency for the Firebase Authentication library
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:18.0.0'

    //Nav Component
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.6"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5"

    // Live Data
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$lifecycleVersion"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycleVersion"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycleVersion"

    //Material Dialog
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:bottomsheets:3.3.0'

    //RecyclerView
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'

    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.1'

    //interceptor
    implementation 'com.itkacher.okhttpprofiler:okhttpprofiler:1.0.7'

    //Retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.8.0"
    implementation 'org.conscrypt:conscrypt-android:2.2.1'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Top-level build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.31"

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}


task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

settings.gradel

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
rootProject.name = "Exaple app"
include ':app'
```

getting this error
[image: eroor]

I have already done some stuff like clean project, rebuild and invalidate caches, and restart. But still getting the same error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post your root gradle.app file?

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS check now

Comment: could you upload also the build.gradle file? The project one do you have google() in repositiories{...}?

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS yes uploaded

Comment: even if you tap on the gradle button (sync) it doesn't let you import GSON? Have you tried with the implementation of my answer to check if is something with the library or not?

Comment: yes it's working after importing GSON but this is not the solution. com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0 has that as dependency though. So it shouldn't be necessary

Comment: Which file does this happen at? Retrofit, or your own code? Because if it's your own code, unless the retrofit-gson package has `api com.google:gson` as it's dependency, you won't get a transitive dependency from Retrofit, and you still need to add direct GSON dependency so your code can use it, as @Skizo-ozᴉʞS said.

Comment: However, [it does have something like that](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit-converters/gson/build.gradle)

Comment: @Shark correct, if he wants to use Gson in your own code he should need api instead of implementation

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement also the [`GSON dependency`](https://github.com/google/gson)

You missing this I'd say

```
implementation("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.9")
```

Comment: `com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0` has that as dependency though. So it shouldn't be necessary to add it yourself as well, but yeah it wouldn't hurt to try